# Ctrl+Shift+C not working to copy from terminal (either gnome terminal or roxterm)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Somehow in my fresh installed ubuntu box, CTRL+SHIFT+C is not copying the selected text, even though the edit menu "Copy" works and says that CTRL+SHIFT+C is bound to copy the selected text.

How can I get CTRL+SHIFT+C working again?

Comment: Is this in a "real" Ubuntu installation on hardware, or a VM or remote installation?

Answer (score 0):

Using xev I found out that the key combination wasn't sending any event at all. Doing some research on my computar model (MSI G72 6QD Dominator), I found out that this was due to a buggy Firmware.

I upgraded my firmware and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Remember to choose your own answer as accepted when it's available to you :)